# Проверка построения графика в PlotWidget

Tags: python, pyside2, plotwidget

Имеется интерфейс, на который добавлен PlotWidget. По нажатии кнопки строится график, однако, при повторном нажатии он строит второй график поверх первого. Теперь вопрос, как сделать такую проверку, чтобы график не строился, если он уже построен.

Код для графика с кнопкой следующий:

```
self.ui.difBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.difract())

def difract(self):
    ...
    styles = {'color': 'r', 'font-size': '12px'}
    pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 0.05, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
    self.ui.graphicsView.setLabel('left', 'Y', **styles)
    self.ui.graphicsView.setLabel('bottom', 'X', **styles)
    self.ui.graphicsView.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(y=False)
    self.ui.graphicsView.plot(x, arr, pen=pen)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.